# How to check if Pandas value is null or zero using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame created with Pandas that contains numbers. I need to check if the values that I extract from this data frame are nulls or zeros. So I am trying the following:

```
a = df.ix[[0], ['Column Title']].values  
if a != 0 or not math.isnan(float(a)):
    print "It is neither a zero nor null"
```

While it does appear to work, sometimes I get the following error:

```
TypeError: don't know how to convert scalar number to float
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the value of `a` that causes the error.

Comment: That looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please post what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I'm incredibly new to pandas, so I could be completely wrong here, but to extract the not null values couldn't you do `df[df['Column Title'] is not None]`?

Comment: @CoryMadden null values are represented as `np.nan` by default in pandas

Comment: `math.isnan(np.nan) == np.nan`

Comment: @DYZ When I print the value, I get [[None]].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your code to extract a single value from a series will return list of list format with a single value:

For Example: [[1]]

so try changing your code

```
 a = df.ix[[0], ['Column Title']].values
```

to

```
 a = df.ix[0, 'Column Title']
```

then try

```
math.isnan(float(a))
```

this will work!!

Comment: `ix` is deprecated in 0.20. Use `iloc` for index based addressing or `loc` otherwise.